# Android: How do I call a method of the main class from the preference activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, listener

I have the main activity class with a `TextView` and a settings activity (generated from the Android's Studio template).

On the settings activity, I've declared many settings. The `TextView` on the main activity shows one of this settings, this is made by a function that loads the current state of all preferences and saves them on variables.

If I change something on the settings activity the listener will execute, but the value won't be updated on the main activity.

I can't use `onResume()` method because it's also executed the first time the app is launched.

I've tried sending an Intent and starting the main class from the listener, but that creates a new instance of the main class, and only allows you to change just one preference because the listener triggers.

My main activity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

private double _lat;


public void loadPrefs(){

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    _lat = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("lat", ""));

    //updates the iu
    TextView helloThere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_hello_world);
    helloThere.setText(Double.toString(_lat));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String changes = getIntent().getStringExtra("prefChanged");
    if(changes != null)
        Log.d("DEBUG!!!!", changes);
    else
        Log.d("DEBUG!!!!", "No changes!!!!");
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadPrefs();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        // Launch Settings activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this is the settings activity (look the function called `onSharedPreferenceChanged`):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
/**
 * Determines whether to always show the simplified settings UI, where
 * settings are presented in a single list. When false, settings are shown
 * as a master/detail two-pane view on tablets. When true, a single pane is
 * shown on tablets.
 */
private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Log.d("DEBUG!!","LISTENER!!");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("prefChanged","Something changed...");
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
}

/**
 * Shows the simplified settings UI if the device configuration if the
 * device configuration dictates that a simplified, single-pane UI should be
 * shown.
 */
private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        return;
    }

    // In the simplified UI, fragments are not used at all and we instead
    // use the older PreferenceActivity APIs.

    // Add 'general' preferences.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    // Add 'notifications' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

    // Add 'data and sync' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    //fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    //fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_data_sync);
    //getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);

    // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences to
    // their values. When their values change, their summaries are updated
    // to reflect the new value, per the Android Design guidelines.
    //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
    //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_ringtone"));
    //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the simplified settings UI should be shown. This is
 * true if this is forced via {@link #ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS}, or the device
 * doesn't have newer APIs like {@link PreferenceFragment}, or the device
 * doesn't have an extra-large screen. In these cases, a single-pane
 * "simplified" settings UI should be shown.
 */
private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
    return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || !isXLargeTablet(context);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}

/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}


/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("fixed_lat_long"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_ringtone"));
    }
}
```

}

Bonus question: I've generated the settings activity using the Android's Studio template, I've noticed that there's no `onCreate()` method, is this normal? What does executed when I call the `startactivity()` function from the main activity?

Thank you.

PS: Maybe I've posted too many code to solve the question, sorry I just started with Android and feel like a noob.

Comment: you should use onActivityResult in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not trying to change the UI of MainActivity from `SettingsActivity` ! The management of the `MainActivity`'s UI should only be done by itself.

Take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). You will see that the `onResume()` method of the `MainActivity` will be called when the Activity will come back on the foreground. So two solutions :

1. You call `loadPrefs()` in the `onResume()`. You tell you can't do it, but I don't understand why (maybe I miss some details)
2. In the `onResume()` method, call `loadPrefs()` only if changes are detected.

Again : do not try to call a method of `MainActivity` from another class : it's a non-sense in Android world.

**Bonus anwser**

The `onCreate()` method is declared in the `Activity` class and so has a default behavior. If you want to modify the default behavior (i.e. declaring your own UI components), you can override it (doing so when adding @Override annotation). So by default, there is no absolut need to override it. And if not override the default implementation will be called. It's an OOP basis ;)

Comment: I clearly needed a break. Your answer helped me. I don't know what I made when I tried to call loadPrefs() from onResume() but didn't work. I guess I was too much focused on send information from one class to another. Now it's working, thanks. And sorry for the bonus question, I knew that, but I didn't see it clear 3h ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to start main activity from settings activity
2. Call `loadPrefs()` from main activity's `onResume()` rather than from `onCreate()`
3. There is `onCreate()` method in settings activity.

Comment: Yes, that's right! I just got stuck of my own thoughts. Sorry, I can't upvote yet. Thank you.